# Does AngularJs work without bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to start using Angular, but i noticed all tutorials include bootstrap first lesson bootstrapping.. I'm not a big fan of grid systems and css frameworks so my question is can you use Angular without bootstrap or the bootstrap is required?

Comment: Yes you can use without bootstrap

Comment: don't confuse the angular bootstrap process with `bootstrap.js`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AngularJS has no dependencies on other libraries. It even includes a stripped-down version of jQuery, but it will use the full jQuery library if it's loaded before AngularJS.